# Zero position matters: one selection problem

Tags: r, regex, string

I'd like to match some results by a rule. In my case:

```
original.names <- c("TL-13","TL-09","TL-12","TL-19A","TL-11","TL-20","TL-16",
"TL-15","TL-14","TL-10","TL-18","TL-19","TL-08A","TL-07A","TL-17A","TL-17",
"TL-21","TL-09A","TL-22","TL-08","TL-05","TL-03","TL-06","TL-07","TL-02","TL-04","TL-01") 

selection <- c(1)

which(original.names==selection)
#integer(0)
```

But in my case `TL-01` is `1`. If I make `which(gsub("TL-|0","",original.names)==selection)`, it doesn't work too
because `10` and `01` are different and `gsub` turns equal. Sometimes I have something like `8A` (number-alphabetic) and I need to consider this situation too.

Please any help with it?

Comment: Should `8` match only `TL-08` or also `TL-08A` and is it possible to use `8A` in selection and if yes should `8A` match only `TL-08A` or also `TL-08`?

Comment: Hi @GKi `8` just only match with `TL-08` and not `TL-08A`.

Comment: Maybe this condition should be empathized in the questions as some answers are returning for `selection <- 8` `13` and `20` where you only want to get `20` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to remove all character strings from your `original.names`, then convert it to integer type before you can do a comparison.

```
original.names <- c("TL-13","TL-09","TL-12","TL-19A","TL-11","TL-20","TL-16",
                    "TL-15","TL-14","TL-10","TL-18","TL-19","TL-08A","TL-07A","TL-17A","TL-17",
                    "TL-21","TL-09A","TL-22","TL-08","TL-05","TL-03","TL-06","TL-07","TL-02","TL-04","TL-01") 

selection <- 1

which(as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", original.names)) == selection)
[1] 27
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach to @benson23 but capturing the required value instead of removing.

```
which(as.integer(sub('TL-(\\d+).*', '\\1', original.names)) == selection)
#[1] 27
```

This captures the numbers that occurs after `TL-`, converts it to integer and compares it with `selection`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option using `parse_number`, although we have to wrap with `abs` as `readr` will take the dash to be a negative.

```
library(readr)

which(abs(parse_number(original.names)) == selection)

# [1] 27
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_pad`:

```
library(stringr)

which(str_match(original.names, '\\d+')== 
        str_pad(selection, 2, pad = "0"))

[1] 27
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove everything before `-` and also the following `0`.

```
selection <- 1
which(sub("^.*-0*", "", original.names) %in% sub("^0*", "", selection))
#[1] 27

selection <- "8A"
which(sub("^.*-0*", "", original.names) %in% sub("^0*", "", selection))
#[1] 13

selection <- "01"
which(sub("^.*-0*", "", original.names) %in% sub("^0*", "", selection))
#[1] 27

selection <- c(1, "8A")
which(sub("^.*-0*", "", original.names) %in% sub("^0*", "", selection))
#[1] 13 27
```